# how to get img src url to python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get the following scr url.

[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import date
import openpyxl
import time

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

img_class = 'thumbnail_thumb_wrap__1pEkS _wrapper' #div
img_xpath = '/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/div/div[1]/li/div/div[1]/div/a/img'
img_css = '.thumbnail_thumb_wrap__1pEkS .thumbnail_thumb__3Agq6:before'

item_img = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, img_xpath).__getattribute__('src')

print(item_img)
```

I searched by Xpath, css_select, and class_name, but I see an error message that none of them have 'src'.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use the `.get_attribute("src")` method, instead of the `__getattribute__` method. The former is implemented by Selenium as a method to get an attribute from the webpage, while the latter is a builtin Python method to try and get the attribute of the Python object.

See here for the Selenium [`get_attribute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) documentation, and here for the Python [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) method that you should not use in this situation.

---

##### Example

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

img_xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/img'
driver.get("https://github.com")
item_web_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, img_xpath)
item_img = item_web_element.get_attribute("src")
print("The source is:", item_img)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: If I put '.get_attribute("src")', the following error message occurs.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'. Did you mean: '.__getattribute__.'?

Comment: What is the problem?...T.T

Comment: Ahh, yes. I misread and thought you were using `find_element` (as in, singular). The problem now is that it is returning a list of elements, unsurprisingly. If you're strictly only interested in 1 element, then perhaps you can use [`find_element`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.event_firing_webdriver.EventFiringWebDriver.find_element) or any of the methods below it. Otherwise, if you want multiple elements, you can iterate over the multiple elements and apply `element.get_attribute("src")` on each of them.

Comment: item_img = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, img_xpath)
    item_imgs = item_img.get_attribute("src")#src

Comment: This will result in the same message.AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'. Did you mean: '.__getattribute__.'

Comment: How about `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, img_xpath).get_attribute("src")`?

Comment: This will result in the same message...T^T

Comment: "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'. Did you mean: '.__getattribute__.' I'm in the hell of the message.

Comment: It does work. Please be precise. It's `find_element`, not `find_elements`. Because your question does not include e.g. the `driver.get`, I can't actually help you reproduce this, but I've included a similar example in my answer via an edit.

Comment: Ah! I saw your writing again.
The modification to a single case was successful. I was a fool..Thank you very much.
But you need src of many images in the same location.
How can I solve this?